# How do I add sections to a binding array of structs that I can update?

Tags: list, swiftui, foreach, state, bindable

I've been looking for a few days and I'm still can't find a solution.

I'd like to group a list of structs that are binding in a list, and still be able to update them.

In the example below I'd like to be able to toggle isOn and the bindable array be updated. This is as close as I've got...

```
enum UserType: Int, CaseIterable {
    case one = 1
    case two = 2
}

struct User: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var type: UserType
    var isOn: Bool
}

struct UserView: View {


@State var users: [User] = [
    User(name: "James", type: .one, isOn: false),
    User(name: "Josh", type: .two, isOn: false),
    User(name: "Jim", type: .one, isOn: false),
    User(name: "Jake", type: .two, isOn: false)
]

var body: some View {
    
    List(){
        ForEach(UserType.allCases) { type in
            Section(header: Text("\(type.rawValue)")) {
                ForEach(users) { user in
                    Text("user.name")
                    Toggle(isOn: user, label: Text("isOn"))
                }

            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change your Data models to a `class` instead of a `struct`.

It is how Apple recommends managing model data

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

It requires changing the model a little

```
class User: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    @Published var id: UUID
    @Published var name: String
    @Published var type: UserType
    @Published var isOn: Bool
    
    init(id: UUID = UUID(), name: String, type: UserType, isOn: Bool) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
        self.isOn = isOn
    }
}
```

And using `@ObservedObject` to see changes and use `@Binding` for the value types.

```
struct RowView: View {
    @ObservedObject var user: User
    var body: some View {
        Text(user.name)
        Toggle(isOn: $user.isOn, label: {
            Text("isOn")
        })
    }
}
```

Then your `UserView` can look something like.

```
struct UserView: View {
    @State var users: [User] = [
        User(name: "James", type: .one, isOn: false),
        User(name: "Josh", type: .two, isOn: false),
        User(name: "Jim", type: .one, isOn: false),
        User(name: "Jake", type: .two, isOn: false)
    ]
    var grouped: [UserType: [User]] {
        Dictionary(grouping: users) { element in
            element.type
        }
    }
    var body: some View {
        
        List{
            ForEach(Array(grouped), id:\.key) { (type, users) in
                Section(header: Text("\(type.rawValue)")) {
                    ForEach(users) { user in
                        RowView(user: user)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For iOS 17 `@Published` and `ObservableObject` are no longer used you use use `@Observable` but you can adapt your code with a few changes.

```
@Observable
class User: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID = .init()
    var name: String = ""
    var type: UserType = UserType.allCases.randomElement()!
    var isOn: Bool = Bool.random()
    
    init(id: UUID = UUID(), name: String, type: UserType, isOn: Bool) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
        self.isOn = isOn
    }
}
```

And use `@Bindable` for the row.

```
struct RowView: View {
    @Bindable var user: User
    var body: some View {
        Text(user.name)
        Toggle(isOn: $user.isOn, label: {
            Text("isOn")
        })
    }
}
```