# How to retrieve binding from published property during ForEach

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a view with multiple buttons. The number of buttons is dynamic and I want to be able to select them. I have a viewModel which contains the buttonViewModels. However, when I iterate over the buttonViewModels, I cannot find the correct pattern/syntax to change the buttonViewModels properly.

```
struct SomeView: View {
  @StateObject var viewModel: SomeViewModel
  var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 12) {
      ForEach(viewModel.buttonViewModels, id: \.id) { vm in
        CustomButton(isSelected: vm.$isSelected) // This is a published property, when we want a binding
      }
    }
  }
}


class SomeViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var buttonViewModels: [ButtonViewModel] = []
}

class ButtonViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var isSelected: Bool
  let id: String = UUID().uuidString

  init(isSelected: Bool) {
    self.isSelected = isSelected
  }
}

public struct CustomButton: View {
  @Binding public var isSelected: Bool

  public var body: some View {
    Button {
      self.isSelected.toggle()
    } label: {
      Text("\(isSelected.description)")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: All `ObservableObject`s have to be wrapped with the appropriate wrapper at every level to see changes. You can create subviews to wrap them appropriately. Also `$` goes on the `vm` not the property

Comment: I don't understand your comment @loremipsum, can you post an example please?

I cannot iterate over `viewModel.$buttonViewModels` because it is not a collection type.

Comment: You should look at the Apple SwiftUI tutorials, this is really basic SwiftUI and you seem to be approaching the "hard" way.

Comment: Can you elaborate why this is the "hard way"? If you could provide an example of the "simple way" that would be great

Comment: The Apple SwiftUI tutorials are the simple way. You probably have programming experience but SwiftUI is different and very strict, I am not going to create a tailored example. `@StateObject` should always be `private` "view state" should be managed using a `struct` data models can be a `class`. `ObservableObject` "ViewModel"s are extremely inefficient but yes I know there are a ton of people that show otherwise. Chaining `ObservableObject`s requires more work, so much so that Apple has replaced them in iOS 17 with `@Observable`, take the tutorials. I am not trying to be a butt it is worth it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add sections to a binding array of structs that I can update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76568393/how-do-i-add-sections-to-a-binding-array-of-structs-that-i-can-update)

Comment: Try removing the objects and use the View struct as designed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach where you declare `ButtonViewModel` a `struct`, and
use bindings (`$`) in the `ForEach` loop.

Note, it is not a good idea to nest `ObservableObjects`, this sometimes gives problems during updates.

For more info, see [monitoring data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app)

```
struct SomeView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: SomeViewModel  // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 12) {
            ForEach($viewModel.buttonViewModels) { $vm in  // <-- here
                CustomButton(isSelected: $vm.isSelected)   // <-- here
            }
        }
    }
}

class SomeViewModel: ObservableObject {
    // for testing
    @Published var buttonViewModels: [ButtonViewModel] = [ButtonViewModel(isSelected: true),
                                                          ButtonViewModel(isSelected: true),
                                                          ButtonViewModel(isSelected: false),
                                                          ButtonViewModel(isSelected: true)]
}

struct ButtonViewModel: Identifiable {  // <-- here
    var isSelected: Bool   // <-- here
    let id: String = UUID().uuidString
    
    init(isSelected: Bool) {
        self.isSelected = isSelected
    }
}

public struct CustomButton: View {
    @Binding var isSelected: Bool
    
    public var body: some View {
        Button {
            self.isSelected.toggle()
        } label: {
            Text("\(isSelected.description)")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = SomeViewModel()  // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        SomeView(viewModel: viewModel)  // <-- here
    }
}
```

Comment: This did the trick. Thanks! I will keep in mind about nested observableObjects. However, I am not running into any problems at the moment. I hope I will run into a concrete example of this causing incorrect behavior.