# Why is @Published state variable not updated in UI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an `AppState` class that I share as an environment variable across my whole app to share core data between all views.

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var user: User?
    @Published var matches = Matches(
        status: .NOT_LOADED,
        data: [],
        performedFullLoad: false,
        canFetchMore: false
    )
}
```

The AppState is instantiated in `ContentView`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var appState = AppState()
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if appState.user == nil { // If user isn't signed in, present AuthView
                AuthView()
            }
            else { // If user is signed in, present Matches view
                MatchesView()
            }
        }
        .environmentObject(appState)
    }
}
```

When user logs in, I run the `Matches.loadMatchesList()` function. This updates the data inside `AppState.matches` variable.

```
final class Matches: ObservableObject {
    @Published var status: LoadingStatus
    @Published var data: [Match]
    @Published var performedFullLoad: Bool
    @Published var canFetchMore: Bool
    
    init(status: LoadingStatus, data: [Match], performedFullLoad: Bool, canFetchMore: Bool) {
        self.status = status
        self.data = data
        self.performedFullLoad = performedFullLoad
        self.canFetchMore = canFetchMore
    }
    
    func loadMatchesList(userId: String) async {

        do {
            
            // Fetch matches and parse into parsedMatches variable
            ...
            
            // Store matches
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.status = .LOADED
                self.data = parsedMatches
                self.performedFullLoad = true
                self.canFetchMore = decodedData.count > numOfMatchesToLoad
                
                print("\(parsedMatches.count) matches loaded into state variable") // This prints "2" at runtime
            }
        } catch let error {
            ...
        }
        
    }
}
```

Finally, I display the list of loaded matches in `MatchesView`. This is where the problem arises, because despite the `print` statement confirming that 2 matches have been loaded and inserted into the array, the rendered List comprises of 0 items.

```
struct MatchesView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState
    
    var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                List(appState.matches.data) { match in
                    NavigationLink {
                        MatchDetail(match: match)
                    } label: {
                        MatchRow(match: match)       
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I know for certain that I'm accessing the correct (and only) instance of AppState in MatchesView, because if I render a button which when clicked prints the count of `appState.matches.data.count`, then it prints "2" as well. It's just that the UI doesn't update to display the 2 matches.

Why is the UI not updating despite the access environment variable conforming to `ObservableObject` and the `data` property being `@Published`?

Comment: Nested ObservableObjects don't work out-of-the-box unless you hook up `objectWillChange` to the parent by hand. Instead, consider changing your model to a `struct` and everything will work right away.

Comment: Changing `Matches` from `class` to `struct` (and changing the function inside to `mutating func`) did indeed fix the issue as the UI now contains the loaded data. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76568393/how-do-i-add-sections-to-a-binding-array-of-structs-that-i-can-update/76568657#76568657

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every `ObservableObject` needs to wrapped with a property wrapper to see changes.

`@StateObject` is for initializing.

`@ObservedObject` is for passing around.

`@EnvironmentObject` is for injecting into the environment.

You have to wrap at every level where you want to see changes or make changes.

You can do this by creating subviews.

`@Published` is only capable for emitting changes when the "value" changes. Changing the property of a reference type does not change the value.