# Is it possible to have 2 arrays in the same ForEach in SwiftUI?

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, foreach, protocols

Is it possible to have 2 `structs/arrays` in the same `ForEach` (for the Option 3)? If so, how? All my attempts were unsuccessful.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct Car: Vehicle, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
}

struct Bike: Vehicle, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
}

let cars = [Car(name: "Renault"), Car(name: "Peugeot")]

let bikes = [Bike(name: "Yamaha"), Bike(name: "Honda")]

protocol Vehicle {
    var name: String { get }
}

struct ParentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        // Option 1 OK
        ForEach(cars.sorted { $0.name < $1.name }) { car in
            ChildView(vehicle: car)
        }

        // Option 2 OK
        ForEach(bikes.sorted { $0.name < $1.name }) { bike in
            ChildView(vehicle: bike)
        }

        // Option 3 NOT OK
        ForEach((cars, bikes).sorted { $0.name < $1.name }) { vehicle in
            ChildView(vehicle: vehicle)
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    let vehicle: Vehicle

    var body: some View {
        Text(vehicle.name)
    }
}
```

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: This is not possible because an array has no member `name`. But you could create an array `let vehicles : [Vehicle]`  which can contain cars and bikes.

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean by "an array has no member name"?

Comment: My bad,  I mean a tuple `([Car], [Bike])` has no member `sorted`. You cannot sort the tuple

Comment: Alright, I'll try to see what I can do with `let vehicles: [Vehicle]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative solution for the case when you don't want to or simply cannot change a protocol just to adhere to some UI requirements.

We want to use any type that conforms to `Vehicle` and yet be able to efficiently use List/ForEach by also conforming to `Identifiable`. For this solution we can create a wrapper type for this

```
struct VehicleUI: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let vehicle: any Vehicle
}
```

And then we can map and join the types directly in the view or some model class

```
(cars + bikes)
    .map(VehicleUI.init)
    .sorted(using: KeyPathComparator(\.vehicle.name, order: .forward))
```

Example:

```
struct ParentView: View {
    var vehicles: [VehicleUI]  {
        (cars + bikes)
            .map(VehicleUI.init)
            .sorted(using: KeyPathComparator(\.vehicle.name, order: .forward))
    }
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(vehicles) { vehicle in
                ChildView(vehicle: vehicle.vehicle)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to have 2 structs/arrays in the same ForEach (for the Option 3), use this approach, works for me:

```
    // Option 3 OK now
    ForEach((cars as [any Vehicle]) + (bikes as [any Vehicle]).sorted { $0.name < $1.name }, id: \.name) { vehicle in
        ChildView(vehicle: vehicle).foregroundStyle(.blue)
    }
```

A better way is to use an `id` in the `ForEach` (rather than `name`), such as:

```
 // Option 3 OK now
 ForEach((cars as [any Vehicle]) + (bikes as [any Vehicle]).sorted { $0.name < $1.name }, id: \.id) { vehicle in
     ChildView(vehicle: vehicle).foregroundStyle(.blue)
 }
```

with

```
 protocol Vehicle {
     var id: UUID { get }   // <-- here
     var name: String { get }
 }
```

and

```
struct ChildView: View {
    let vehicle: any Vehicle // <-- here

    var body: some View {
        Text(vehicle.name)
    }
}
```

Comment: It works but not as expected. The list isn't mixed and not sorted by `name`.

Comment: yes, my bad regarding the sorting, I missed the enclosing `(..)`, it should be:
 `ForEach( ((cars as [any Vehicle]) + (bikes as [any Vehicle])).sorted....`

Comment: I tried your updated solution and it works great. I wonder why you don't recommend using the `name` as the `id` btw?

Comment: yes, I don't recommend using the name as the id, because in a `ForEach` loop you need to have unique identifiers.
I know that some car manufacturers, such as "Peugeot" and "Honda", for example, also make bikes, so you could have two names the same.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 17 you can use `@Observable` + Inheritance to easily combine Data Model objects.

```
import Observation

@Observable
class VehicleModel: VehicleProtocol, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String = ""
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class Car: VehicleModel {

}

class Bike: VehicleModel {
    
}
```

Then you can combine the 2 arrays easily into one.

```
let vehicles : [VehicleModel] = cars + bikes
```

iOS 13-16 support is a bit more complex and inefficient with `ObservableObject` but it is still possible.

[How do I add sections to a binding array of structs that I can update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76568393/how-do-i-add-sections-to-a-binding-array-of-structs-that-i-can-update/76568657#76568657)

You can look at Apple's documentation below.

[Managing model data in your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app)

[Migrating from the Observable Object protocol to the Observable macro](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-from-the-observable-object-protocol-to-the-observable-macro)