# How to merge two different array models in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I try to merge my two structs. I want to merge data, sort and display data in my custom list in SwiftUI.

My models looks like this:

**1st model:**

```
struct BetModel: Identifiable, Hashable, BetProtocol {
    
    
    init(
        id: Int64?,
        date: Date,
        team1: String,
        team2: String,
        selectedTeam: SelectedTeam,
        league: String?,
        amount: NSDecimalNumber,
        odds: NSDecimalNumber,
        category: Category,
        tax: NSDecimalNumber,
        profit: NSDecimalNumber,
        isWon: Bool?,
        betNotificationID: String?,
        score: NSDecimalNumber?
    ) {
        self.id = id
        self.date = date
        self.team1 = team1
        self.team2 = team2
        self.selectedTeam = selectedTeam
        self.league = league
        self.amount = amount
        self.odds = odds
        self.category = category
        self.tax = tax
        self.profit = profit
        self.isWon = isWon
        self.betNotificationID = betNotificationID
        self.score = score
    }

    var id: Int64?
    var date: Date
    let team1: String
    let team2: String
    let selectedTeam: SelectedTeam
    let league: String?
    let amount: NSDecimalNumber
    let odds: NSDecimalNumber
    let category: Category
    let tax: NSDecimalNumber
    let profit: NSDecimalNumber
    let isWon: Bool?
    let betNotificationID: String?
    let score: NSDecimalNumber?
}

enum SelectedTeam: Int {
    case team1
    case team2
}

enum Category: String, CaseIterable {
    case football
    case basketball
    case f1
    case tenis
    case volleyball
}
```

**2nd model:**

```
struct BetslipModel: Identifiable, Hashable, BetProtocol {

    init(
        id: Int64?,
        date: Date,
        name: String,
        amount: NSDecimalNumber,
        odds: NSDecimalNumber,
        category: Category,
        tax: NSDecimalNumber,
        profit: NSDecimalNumber,
        isWon: Bool?,
        betNotificationID: String?,
        score: NSDecimalNumber?
    ) {
        self.id = id
        self.date = date
        self.name = name
        self.amount = amount
        self.odds = odds
        self.category = category
        self.tax = tax
        self.profit = profit
        self.isWon = isWon
        self.betNotificationID = betNotificationID
        self.score = score
    }

    var id: Int64?
    let name: String
    var date: Date
    let amount: NSDecimalNumber
    let odds: NSDecimalNumber
    let category: Category
    let tax: NSDecimalNumber
    let profit: NSDecimalNumber
    let isWon: Bool?
    let betNotificationID: String?
    let score: NSDecimalNumber?
}
```

I tried to use this answer from stackoverflow:
[Sort Two Arrays of Different Types into One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32975491/sort-two-arrays-of-different-types-into-one?noredirect=1&lq=1)

but it's not working for me.
I created protocol, with two values which i need:

**My protocol based on previous link**

```
protocol BetProtocol: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: Int64? { get set }
    var date: Date { get set }
}
```

**After this, i tried to merge my data in ViewModel:**

This is my code in VM to merge lists. I have two models (single list and combined bets). I would like to display a list sorted by date in one of my views. Depending on the type, NavigationLink should lead to a screen with details for the BetModel/BetslipModel model. I get my data from DB to publishers.

```
 @Published
    var historyBets: [BetModel]? = []

    @Published
    var betslipHistory: [BetslipModel]? = []

    var mergedBets: [any BetProtocol]? {
        ((historyBets ?? []) + (betslipHistory ?? []))
    }
```

However, when I tried to merge the data by displaying the data via print in the console, I got the result "*Optional([])*". Does anyone have any idea how I could use a combination of these two models? I don't know what's causing this error, I assume there's something wrong with the protocol. When I tried to use the view in view like below, the app didn't start. Given this and the previous output from the console, something is wrong with the merge.

**View:**

```
 LazyVStack(spacing: 12) {
                        ForEach(
                            vm.mergedBets, id: \.id) { bet in
                                if let betModel = bet as? BetModel {
                                    NavigationLink(
                                        destination: BetDetailsScreen(bet: bet)
                                    ) {
                                        BetListElement(bet: bet, currency: vm.currency)
                                    }
                                } else if let betslipModel = bet as? BetslipModel {
                                    // Here you can use betslipModel-specific views or properties
                                    NavigationLink(
                                        destination: BetslipDetailsScreen(bet: bet)
                                    ) {
                                        BetslipListElement(bet: bet, currency: vm.currency)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                    }
```

When I display one list of items I don't get any error. I don't know how to combine the two models. They are actually different, but they share common elements such as date or amount. I'd like to create a linked list so I can sort them in a view or use the .map function later.

Comment: *...by displaying the data via print in the console...* where? And *...what's causing this error...* what error? It's unclear how/where the data source is declared and populated.  In your case an enum with associated values might be a better choice, it avoids the type check at runtime.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you trying to merge the data or display two different models in a view?

Comment: And why are you saying „array“ but show struct?

Comment: I’m sorry for the unclear question. I’m so stupid, i didnt paste all of my message & code.  I updated my answer and code from ViewModel.

Yes, I have two models (single list and combined bets). I would like to display a list sorted by date in one of my views. Depending on the type, NavigationLink should lead to a screen with details for the BetModel/BetslipModel model. I get my data from DB to publishers.

Comment: When I tried to display the array for mergedBets from my console code (by calling it in init), I was getting the aforementioned Optional([]). When I display one list of items I don't get any error. I don't know how to combine the two models. They are actually different, but they share common elements such as date or amount. I'd like to create a linked list so I can sort them in a view or use the .map function later.

I’m learning swift so i do some basic mistakes.

Comment: You need to know the data model to properly solve this. What is the unique identifier(s) of the first struct and what is the corresponding property/ies in the second struct. When you know that then you know how to combine them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to have 2 arrays in the same ForEach in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76664146/is-it-possible-to-have-2-arrays-in-the-same-foreach-in-swiftui)