# How to add a row in SwiftUI list which has sections

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-list

I want to simply add a row in a List in SwiftUI, as in **insertRowAtindexpath** in **UIKIT**

I did my due research and found out appending a section works while adding a row in section does not work.

Am i missing something.

The code

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestList: View {
    
    
    @State var sections : [SectionModel] =
    [
        SectionModel(id: 1, rows:
                    [
                        RowModel(id: 1, name: "1"),
                             RowModel(id: 2, name: "2")
                    ]
               ),
        
        SectionModel(id: 2, rows:
                    [
                        RowModel(id: 1, name: "1"),
                        RowModel(id: 2, name: "2")
                    ]
               )
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        List{
            
            ForEach (sections) { section  in
                
                Section(){
                    ForEach(section.rows) {row in
                        
                        Button {
                            addRow() // does not work
                            addSection() // works
                        } label: {
                            Text(row.name)
                        }
                    }
                    
                    
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
     func addRow() {
         
         sections[0].addRow(row: RowModel.init(id: 10, name: "10"))
    }
    
    func addSection() {
        
        sections.append(SectionModel.init(id: 23, rows: [RowModel.init(id: 10, name: "10")]))
   }

}

class RowModel : Identifiable{
    
    var id: Int
    let name : String
    
    init(id: Int, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}

class SectionModel : Identifiable{

    var id  : Int
    var rows : [ RowModel]
 
    init(id: Int, rows:[ RowModel]) {
        self.id = id
        self.rows = rows
    }
    
    func addRow (row : RowModel) {
        
        rows.append(row)
        
    }
    
}
```

**UPDATE**

This works,

```
    func addrow() {
        
        var section = sections[0]
        section.addRow(row: RowModel.init(id: 10, name: "10"))
        sections[0] = section
   }
```

Specific thing I could note here is,

If the **section** (which is an item/element in the sections which is the one referred in **ForEach** as a datasource) is directly changed, it has the effect in the UI.

if any item/element (Row) inside the section changes (2nd level elements) there is no effect in the UI.

Also, as given in the selected answer, the section is passed-on on button click, changes the section hence it works.

Struct or Class has nothing to do with this problem.

Comment: You must not mix class and structs. Your tow and sections models should structs. In case you have an array element which is a class, modifying the contents of the class will not trigger modification because the class object is still the same (pointer does not change)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add sections to a binding array of structs that I can update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76568393/how-do-i-add-sections-to-a-binding-array-of-structs-that-i-can-update)

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the models. As mentioned by @ptit-xav they work best in `SwiftUI` if they are structs. It is also important that the ids are `let`s not `var`s as the identity of an object has to be stable.

```
struct RowModel: Identifiable {
    
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

struct SectionModel : Identifiable{

    let id = UUID()
    var rows : [RowModel]
 
    init(rows: [RowModel] = [RowModel]()) {
        self.rows = rows
    }
    
    mutating func add(row: RowModel) {
        rows.append(row)
    }
}
```

Because `SwiftUI` view bodies are just a computed properties based on the model you cannot add a row to the table view itself, but you have to add it to the model and it will be reflected in the view. If I understand your needs correctly you would need something like this to enable users to create both new rows and new sections:

```
struct TestList: View {
    
    @State var sections : [SectionModel] = [
        SectionModel(
            rows: [
                RowModel(name: "row 1"),
                RowModel(name: "row 2")
            ]
        ),
        SectionModel(
            rows: [
                RowModel(name: "row 1"),
                RowModel(name: "row 2")
            ]
        )
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        List{
            // existing sections
            ForEach (sections) { section  in
                Section {
                    // existing rows
                    ForEach(section.rows) {row in
                        Text(row.name)
                    }
                    // last row is a button that lets the user create new rows
                    Button {
                        addRow(in: section)
                    } label: {
                        Text("Add row")
                    }
                }
            }
            //last section is a button that lets users create new sections
            Button(action: addSection) {
                Text("Add section")
            }
        }
    }

    func addRow(in section: SectionModel) {
        guard let index = sections.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == section.id }) else { return}
        sections[index].add(row: RowModel(name: "new row"))
    }

    func addSection() {
        sections.append(SectionModel())
    }

}
```

[image: list with ability to add both rows and sections]